# GIT correct workflow for my Branch structure

Tags: git, bash, github, version-control

I started to implement a GIT repository following a specific Workflow.
The workflow is the following:

```
                                v0.1               v0.2 
                                 /                  / 
 releases-------------------------------------------------
/                               |                   |
main--------------------------[0.1]---------------[0.2]                   
\                            /    \               /
 development---             /      \             /
               \           /        \           /
                feature-ABC          feature-XYZ
```

1. `main` contains the latest **stable code** where any developer can just `git checkout -> build -> deploy`
2. `main` contains **tags** used to identify a `release`
3. Every **release version** is branched into `release` branch
4. `development` is the **starting branch** for a developer. After a `commit` the Build Server will Build/Deploy the solution into a `development environment`
5. If a Dev needs to work on a **story/feature** they branch from `development` and push back into `development` when done using a branch naming of `feature/name` or `hotfix/bugname`
6. When `development` gets stable, it is merged back into `main` and the release is **tagged** and get deployed `in staging`
7. a **Release version** is created into `release`

#### Questions

Now, in order to adopt this workflow, I created a sequence of `GIT commands` that a developer should execute. Can you verify the correctness?

Also, how can I ensure that main and development are always *properly* in sync?

#### First Time (assuming there is no development branch yet)

```bash
$ git checkout master
$ git branch -b development
$ git push -u origin development
```

#### Development starts

```bash
$ git checkout development
$ git branch -b feature/my_feature

... iteration ...
 $ git add ...
 $ git commit -m "My Comment"
 $ git push origin feature/my_feature
... iteration ...
```

#### Developer is done with Feature/Bug

```bash
$ git checkout development
$ git merge feature/my_feature
... resolve conflicts ...
$ git commit -m "Merge from feature/my_feature"
$ git push -u origin development
```

#### Tester approve latest Development release

```bash
$ git checkout master
$ git merge development
... resolve conflicts ...
$ git tag -a v0.1 -m "my version 0.1"
$ git commit -m "Merge from development"
$ git push -u origin master --tags

$ git checkout master
$ git branch v0.1
$ git commit -m "my version 0.1"
$ git push -u origin v0.1
```

Comment: If it's effortless merge's you're after then dev's should be rebasing feature branches regularly. Or at least merging in master (though that's not an approach I like, it leads to messy commit histories). However you're always going to have to solve the same conflicts, you're just changing when you're going to have to solve them.

Comment: I suggest to use git-flow, it's a pretty good workflow for the most development processes with tooling and documentation available.
And these resources can make on-boarding of new developers faster.

Check it out: http://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/2010/why-arent-you-using-git-flow/

Comment: @Raffaeu have you get the answer which helps you solve the problem? If yes, please mark it. And it will help others who have similar questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commands can meet the work flow you plan to use. But there has some tiny things for you to refer (it's also ok to keep it as original):

1.`git push` with `-u` only need for first time push (set upstream).

2.The release versions are always exist in `release` branch. So you can merge `main` branch into `release` branch instead of creating branch `v0.1`, `v0.2` etc.

To check if `main` and `development` are sync, you can use `git log main..development`. If it has output, that means the `development` branch has commit(s) need to merge into `main` branch.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that we can say, with 100% certainty, that these commands are "correct" for all situations, recognizing that the events in your diagram are nice and linear but development reality may not be.

Still, at a nuts-and-bolts level the only problem that jumps out at me is here:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git branch v0.1
$ git commit -m "my version 0.1"
$ git push -u origin v0.1
```

The commit will fail because it contains no changes.  Although I'd question the need for the `commit` statement (an annotated tag probably makes more sense for what you're trying to do), if you must have a commit then you'll have to pass the `--allow-emtpy` argument to convince git to create one.